# When i modify the mongo db, how can i upload the image?? (node.js, multer)

Tags: node.js, multer

when mongodb is changed(update), if the image is changed, change the db(image path) and upload image and remove the image(before), if is not, just upload the image..

```
router.put('/test/update/:first_idx/:second_idx', isAuthenticated, upload.array('images', 5), TestController.updateSomthing)
```

`upload.array('images'`) at this can i save or remove images depending on the `req.body`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that is very important to consider before saving images to MongoDB is the document size limit. A document can only be at most 16MB. If you are allowing an array of images, especially, you could potentially run into size limit issues when the array gets too large.

You can find more about this limit [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/).

To get around this size limit, store the relative path to the file on the server, and store the file in a folder.

Here is a tutorial on how to use Multer/MongoDB to create a [file store](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/file-upload-with-multer-in-node--cms-32088) like you want. If you want to continue with storing the files in the DB and comparing them, this tutorial will lay that ground for you. You can store the images in Base64 and then check on upload whether another image with that base64 string exists. If it does, don't save it. This is assuming by comparing images, you mean checking to see if the EXACT same image exists.

I do not think it is going to be efficient to compare images to make sure that they are equal, because this sounds very computationally expensive. I would just do a full write-over with every PUT (unless you have to worry about concurrency).